# Umbraco courier sync data back

Tags: umbraco

I'm kind of new to umbraco and content syncen. But I'm wondering how can I sync content from production back to my local database? I only found the scenario where you can push it forward, but not pulling it backward. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Courier can move things where ever it’s configured.

If your local instance is accessible by the production instance, make sure it’s configured in your courier.config and then you should be able to move items there.  But note that since things move over http, the local site needs to be accessible.

If you can’t make your local site accessible, you can create a courier revision in your production instance and then move it to your local instance, by going to the courier section in your local istances and finding to your production instance and pull down the revision.  Then once you have it locally, you can install it.
You may need to break it up into a few packagers as if the packages get large, sometimes courier has issued.